# What's the steps to add an extension to PHP without recompling from source code in linux?

Tags: php, installation, pecl

I heard that PECL can do this job,

can someone provide a hello world demo?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to install? It's likely that the extension is available in your distro's package repository.

Answer (score 1):

If you have PECL installed, it's this simple:

```
pecl install xdebug
```

Installing PEAR / PECL is best accomplished with your distributions packaging system.

Comment: Do I have to enable the extension in php.ini,or it's automatically available ?